# CSS issue : Same code works in codepen but not in local system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a card section in HTML using bootstrap which works as expected in codepen and on the example site but doesn't work in the local system.
Here html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Why Choose Us Section Design With Bootstrap</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.2/css/all.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Why Us Section -->
    <section class="why-us">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="box">
                        <span>01</span>
                        <h4><a href="#">Why Lorem Ipsum</a></h4>
                        <p>There are many variations of passages of available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form</p>
                        <img src="/images/image-one.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="box">
                        <span>02</span>
                        <h4><a href="#">Why do we use it</a></h4>
                        <p>There are many variations of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form</p>
                        <img src="/images/image-two.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="box">
                        <span>03</span>
                        <h4><a href="#">Can I get some</a></h4>
                        <p>There are many variations of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form</p>
                        <img src="/images/image-three.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="box">
                        <span>04</span>
                        <h4><a href="#">Why Lorem Ipsum</a></h4>
                        <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, the majority have suffered alteration in some form</p>
                        <img src="/images/image-four.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="box">
                        <span>05</span>
                        <h4><a href="#">Why do we use it</a></h4>
                        <p>There are many of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form</p>
                        <img src="/images/image-five.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="box">
                        <span>06</span>
                        <h4><a href="#">Can I get some</a></h4>
                        <p>There are variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form</p>
                        <img src="/images/image-six.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End Why Us Section -->
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS code

```
.why-us h2 {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}
.why-us h2::after {
    content: "";
    width: 120px;
    height: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #FFC107;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: -20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.why-us .box {
    padding: 50px 30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
    transition: 0.5s;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #333;
    max-height: 230px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.why-us .box:hover {
    padding: 30px 30px 70px 30px;
    box-shadow: 10px 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.why-us .box img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition:all ease 1s; 
}
.why-us .box:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
}
.why-us .box span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 56px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #6b6060;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 0px;
    line-height: normal;
}
.why-us .box h4 a {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    color: #dadada;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.why-us .box p {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.why-us .box:hover span,
.why-us .box:hover h4 a,
.why-us .box:hover p {
    color: #fff;
}
```

**The cards are not showing images on hover as expected from the sample code.** https://www.markuptag.com/demo/why-choose-us-section-design-with-bootstrap.php

The image appears on hover when I change the z-index=-1 to +ve but then the text doesn't appear on hover

Comment: Are the images in the correct local folder? Does your console show any errors?

Comment: yes in fact im using online image <img src="https://img.icons8.com/bubbles/100/000000/trust.png" />

not working in local system but working in codepen'

Comment: How does your code know it's an online image? And where are you using it - it isn't shown in the code in your question. Several local srcs are shown for imgs. Perhaps you could show us the codepen as it works there?

Comment: yeah, i tried local image as well as online image. the online image worked in codepen and even online image worked if we put the zindex 1 but then text disapear on hover.
this is what i wrote in question as well